# VSCode: Can I open individual files instead of workspaces?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Opening whole directories (each one requiring a new window) doesn’t play well with editing lots of little scripts/config files scattered in different folders.

Comment: maybe you need a `workspace` which can include folders in different locations.Open a new VSCode window with nothing, `start` - `add workspace folder`.You can save the profile to anywhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can! Here are three ways:

1. Either by running `code {yourfilename here}` in a terminal.
2. Dragging the file from a file explorer onto the open VSCode window.
3. Use the menu item "File/Open file... (Ctrl + O)", see image.

[image: Open file in VSCode]

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to open a folder in VSCode!

In VSCode create a *New Window* (instance) and open all the files you're interested in from anywhere on your disk.

If you want to keep this selection for later, you can *Save Workspace As ..* for later usage.